# `Invalid Character Error `while executing oracle procedure using `getclobval()`

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, listagg

The following procedure compiles successfully on `ctrll + S` (shows VALID) but on execution throws the error : `Invalid character error`  while executing this `procedure` on `SQL DEVELOPER`.
I don't see anywhere I have a invalid character.

The following is the code to Create table and insert values:-

```
 CREATE TABLE tempt( "set" VARCHAR2(1), "level" VARCHAR2(1), category VARCHAR2(3), value INT );

INSERT INTO tempt
SELECT 'A', 'Z', 'ABC', 847549 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'Y', 'ABC', 955808 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'X', 'ABC', 983462 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'Z', 'GHI', 762369 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'Y', 'DEF', 615863 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'X', 'DEF', 474257 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'Z', 'ABC', 959843 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'Y', 'ABC', 821704 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'X', 'ABC', 377211 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'Z', 'DEF', 945053 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'Y', 'DEF', 919120 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'Y', 'ABC', 821704 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'X', 'ABC', 377211 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'Z', 'DEF', 945053 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'Y', 'DEF', 919120 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 'X', 'ABC', 377211 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 'Z', 'DEF', 945053 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 'Y', 'GHI', 919120 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'E', 'X', 'ABC', 377211 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'E', 'Z', 'DEF', 945053 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'E', 'Y', 'ABC', 919120 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'E', 'Z', 'ABC', 945053 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'E', 'Y', 'DEF', 919120 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'X', 'IJK', 326886 FROM dual
```

This is run inside the procedure window on the the SQL Developer/DB viz:-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SCHEMA.pivot"(v_recordset out sys_refcursor)
AS
--v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       long;
  v_cols_1    long;
  v_cols_2    clob; 

BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG( ''''||"level"||''' AS "'||"level"||'"' , ',' )
          WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY "level" DESC )
    INTO v_cols_1
    FROM (
          SELECT DISTINCT "level"
            FROM tempt
          );

SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT (
          RTRIM (
           XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (
                        e,
                          'MAX(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = '
                      || CHR (39)
                       || CATEGORY
                       || CHR (39)
                       || ' THEN '
                      || CHR (39)
                      || "level"
                       || CHR (39)
                      || ' END) AS '
                       || "level"
                      || '_'
                       || CATEGORY
                      || '',
                       ',')
                    ORDER BY 1 DESC).EXTRACT ('//text()').getclobval (),
           ','))
    INTO v_cols_2
   FROM (SELECT DISTINCT "level", CATEGORY
          FROM tempt);
                      

  v_sql :=
  'SELECT "set", ('|| v_cols_2 ||')
     FROM
     (
      SELECT *
        FROM tempt
           PIVOT
           (
            MAX(value) FOR "level" IN ( '|| v_cols_1 ||' )
           )
          )
          GROUP BY "set"
          ORDER BY "set"'; 
      v_sql := REPLACE (v_sql, '&amp;apos;', CHR (39));
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sql);
       
      OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
 end pivot;
```

**EDIT 1** : I ran the query provided in the answer ,though compiled sucessfully I get a `Invalid Character`
Error :-

`00911. 00000 -  "invalid character" *Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language Reference Manual.`
I have seen the other posts with same question and tried out everything but doesnt seem to fix the issue. Line it shows for the error is `OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;`

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pivot (v_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
  2  AS
  3     --v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  4     v_sql     LONG;
  5     v_cols_1  LONG;
  6     v_cols_2  CLOB;
  7  BEGIN
  8     SELECT LISTAGG ('''' || "level" || ''' AS "' || "level" || '"', ',')
  9               WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "level" DESC)
 10       INTO v_cols_1
 11       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT "level"
 12               FROM tempt);
 13
 14     SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT (
 15               RTRIM (
 16                  XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (
 17                             e,
 18                                'MAX(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = '
 19                             || CHR (39)
 20                             || CATEGORY
 21                             || CHR (39)
 22                             || ' THEN '
 23                             || CHR (39)
 24                             || "level"
 25                             || CHR (39)
 26                             || ' END) AS '
 27                             || "level"
 28                             || '_'
 29                             || CATEGORY
 30                             || '',
 31                             ',')
 32                          ORDER BY 1 DESC).EXTRACT ('//text()').getclobval (),
 33                  ','))
 34       INTO v_cols_2
 35       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT "level", CATEGORY
 36               FROM tempt);
 37
 38     v_sql := 'SELECT "set", ' || v_cols_2 || '
 39       FROM
 40       (
 41        SELECT *
 42          FROM tempt
 43             PIVOT
 44             (
 45              MAX(value) FOR "level" IN ( ' || v_cols_1 || ' )
 46             )
 47            )
 48            GROUP BY "set"
 49            ORDER BY "set"';
 50     v_sql := REPLACE (v_sql, '&amp;apos;', CHR (39));
 51     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_sql);
 52
 53     OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
 54  END pivot;
 55  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

Testing:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  3  BEGIN
  4     pivot (l_rc);
  5  END;
  6  /
SELECT "set", MAX(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'GHI' THEN 'Y' END) AS Y_GHI,MAX(CASE
WHEN CATEGORY = 'ABC' THEN 'Y' END) AS Y_ABC,MAX(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'ABC' THEN
'Z' END) AS Z_ABC,MAX(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'DEF' THEN 'Z' END) AS Z_DEF,MAX(CASE
WHEN CATEGORY = 'IJK' THEN 'X' END) AS X_IJK,MAX(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'GHI' THEN
'Z' END) AS Z_GHI,MAX(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'DEF' THEN 'X' END) AS X_DEF,MAX(CASE
WHEN CATEGORY = 'ABC' THEN 'X' END) AS X_ABC,MAX(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'DEF' THEN
'Y' END) AS Y_DEF
     FROM
     (
      SELECT *
        FROM tempt

PIVOT
           (
            MAX(value) FOR "level" IN ( 'Z' AS "Z",'Y' AS
"Y",'X' AS "X" )
           )
          )
          GROUP BY "set"

ORDER BY "set"

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Running the resulting query produces the following result (snipped):

```
SQL> SELECT "set", MAX(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'GHI  <snip>
ORY = 'DEF' THEN 'Z' END) AS Z_DEF,MAX(CASE WHEN  <snip>
(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'ABC' THEN 'X' END) AS X_A  <snip>
  2       FROM
  3       (
  4        SELECT *
  5          FROM tempt
  6             PIVOT
  7             (
  8              MAX(value) FOR "level" IN ( 'Z'
  9             )
 10            )
 11            GROUP BY "set"
 12            ORDER BY "set"
 13  /

s Y Y Z Z X Z X X Y
- - - - - - - - - -
A Y Y Z Z   Z X X Y
B   Y Z Z X   X X Y
C   Y Z Z     X X Y
D Y Y Z Z   Z X X Y
E   Y Z Z     X X Y

SQL>
```

---

P.S. **Forgot to say**: really, **really**, **REALLY** bad idea naming column using lower case under double quotes.

Comment: unfortunately thats the name of columns given in our tables,I understand those are reserved key words

Comment: Could you tell me where have you run `SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
     l_rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
    BEGIN
       pivot (l_rc);
    END;
    /`

Comment: Yes the PL/SQL block got compiled, but i used the same execution statements you have provided on `Testing window` .. it doesn't work..(which makes sense as its SQL*Plus).I used the inbuilt `run` button on proc window, it gives `invalid character` error

Comment: I wouldn't know, I don't know the "inbuilt RUN button on proc window". Procedure, as well as its query, work correctly - as demonstrated.

Comment: `*Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
           character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
           any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
           (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
           delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
           Reference Manual.`